# Disable/Enable Ribbon Buttons for MFC Feature Pack

Tags: c++, mfc, mfc-feature-pack

I am using the MFC Feature Pack and I have some buttons on a ribbon bar, instances of CMFCRibbonButton. The problem is that I would like to enable and disable some of them in certain conditions, but at runtime. How can I do this? because there is no specific method for this...I heard that a solution would be to attach/detach the event handlers at runtime, but I do not know how...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

When you create the `CMFCRibbonButton` object you have to specify the associated command ID (see the documentation for the `CMFCRibbonButton` constructor [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb982247.aspx)). Enabling and disabling of ribbon buttons is then done using the usual command update mechanism in MFC, using the [`CCmdUI`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6kc4d8fh.aspx) class.

For example, if you have a ribbon button whose command ID is `ID_MYCOMMAND` and you want to handle this command in your application's view class, you should add these functions to the class:

```
// MyView.h
class CMyView : public CView {
    // ...
    private:
        afx_msg void OnMyCommand();
        afx_msg void OnUpdateMyCommand(CCmdUI* pCmdUI);
        DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
};
```

and implement them in the .cpp file:

```
// MyView.cpp
void CMyView::OnMyCommand() {
    // add command handler code.
}

void CMyView::OnUpdateMyCommand(CCmdUI* pCmdUI) {
    BOOL enable = ...; // set flag to enable or disable the command.
    pCmdUI->Enable(enable);
}
```

You should also add `ON_COMMAND` and `ON_UPDATE_COMMAND_UI` entries to the message map for the `CMyView` class:

```
// MyView.cpp
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CMyView, CView)
    ON_COMMAND(ID_MYCOMMAND, &CMyView::OnMyCommand)
    ON_UPDATE_COMMAND_UI(ID_MYCOMMAND, &CMyView::OnUpdateMyCommand)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()
```

For more information on message maps in MFC, refer to [TN006: Message Maps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0812b0wa.aspx) in MSDN.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

ChrisN gave a pretty perfect answer. You can see an example of exactly how this is done by downloading the VS2008 Sample Pack from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=01AE159F-08CD-495B-8BF4-A48CC395AD7B), and opening the MSOffice2007Demo solution.

When running the sample, look at the "Thumbnails" checkbox in the View tab of the ribbon, it's disabled.

This is controlled by `CMSOffice2007DemoView::OnUpdateViewThumb` which calls `pCmdUI->Enable(FALSE);`. You can change this to call `TRUE` or `FALSE` at runtime to enable/disable the button respectively.